# Web-app hot-reload when running by IIS Express with SSL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl, iis-express, hot-reload

Created project by Micosoft Visual Studio "ASP.NET with React+Redux" template. In that case app running by IIS Express. But hot-reload for react-app doesn't work and shows error in console: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:54691/ws' failed:"

After some research, I found a solution: disable SSL in IIS settings. But how can I achieve using hot reload when SSL is enabled?

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-redux": "~7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.1",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  },
```

launchSettings.json generated by template (SSL enabled)

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:48763",
      "sslPort": 44373
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
```

error message:

```
WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:54691/ws' failed: 
WebSocketClient @   WebSocketClient.js:16
initSocket  @   socket.js:24
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=54691&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10   @   index.js:273
options.factory @   react refresh:6
__webpack_require__
```